# Problem with sub domain domain ssl targeting

Tags: apache, ssl, xampp

Good afternoon, I am directing the interno.monisat.com.br sub-domain to an internal dedicated. When SSL is not used it works normally. However when trying to access via: it is directed to the main domain (monisat.com.br) that is in a hosting.

VHOST:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
  
    ServerName interno.monisat.com.br    
    ServerAlias www.interno.monisat.com.br

    SSLEngine On

    SSLCertificateFile "Cxxx"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "xxx"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "xxx"

    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs">
        Options Indexes
        Order allow,deny    
        Allow from all
        SSLRequireSSL    
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin xxx@monisat.com
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName xxx
 
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs">
        Options Indexes
        Order allow,deny    
        Allow from all 
    </Directory>   
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58218263/how-to-use-different-vhost-config-files-for-apache-with-sni-multiple-ssl-certi/58229205#58229205.  Has to do with the way SSL is handled in Apache, and the default VirtualHost.  Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51371875/2nd-virtual-host-domain-forwards-to-apache-test-page-after-ssl-certificate/51383655#51383655

Comment: my question is not to work with 2 sites! It is only 1 virtual, but this unique virtual is directing to the main domain that is in another hosting! in this case, interno.monisat.com.br is directing to monisat.com.br. Thing that shouldn't happen